# CPU Affinity Masks (Putting Threads on different CPUs)

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads, parallel-processing

I have 4 threads, and I am trying to set thread 1 to run on CPU 1, thread 2 on CPU 2, etc.
However, when I run my code below, the affinity masks are returning the correct values, but when I do a sched_getcpu() on the threads, they all return that they are running on CPU 4.

Anybody know what my problem here is?

Thanks in advance!

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <errno.h>

void *pthread_Message(char *message)
{
    printf("%s is running on CPU %d\n", message, sched_getcpu());
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread1, thread2, thread3, thread4;
    pthread_t threadArray[4];
    cpu_set_t cpu1, cpu2, cpu3, cpu4;
    char *thread1Msg = "Thread 1";
    char *thread2Msg = "Thread 2";
    char *thread3Msg = "Thread 3";
    char *thread4Msg = "Thread 4";
    int thread1Create, thread2Create, thread3Create, thread4Create, i, temp;

    CPU_ZERO(&cpu1);
    CPU_SET(1, &cpu1);
    temp = pthread_setaffinity_np(thread1, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpu1);
    printf("Set returned by pthread_getaffinity_np() contained:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < CPU_SETSIZE; i++)
        if (CPU_ISSET(i, &cpu1))
            printf("CPU1: CPU %d\n", i);

    CPU_ZERO(&cpu2);
    CPU_SET(2, &cpu2);
    temp = pthread_setaffinity_np(thread2, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpu2);
    for (i = 0; i < CPU_SETSIZE; i++)
        if (CPU_ISSET(i, &cpu2))
            printf("CPU2: CPU %d\n", i);

    CPU_ZERO(&cpu3);
    CPU_SET(3, &cpu3);
    temp = pthread_setaffinity_np(thread3, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpu3);
    for (i = 0; i < CPU_SETSIZE; i++)
        if (CPU_ISSET(i, &cpu3))
            printf("CPU3: CPU %d\n", i);

    CPU_ZERO(&cpu4);
    CPU_SET(4, &cpu4);
    temp = pthread_setaffinity_np(thread4, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpu4);
    for (i = 0; i < CPU_SETSIZE; i++)
        if (CPU_ISSET(i, &cpu4))
            printf("CPU4: CPU %d\n", i);

    thread1Create = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, (void *)pthread_Message, thread1Msg);
    thread2Create = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, (void *)pthread_Message, thread2Msg);
    thread3Create = pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, (void *)pthread_Message, thread3Msg);
    thread4Create = pthread_create(&thread4, NULL, (void *)pthread_Message, thread4Msg);

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread3, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread4, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're trying to set the affinity of threads that you did not initialize.

Edit: Ok, let me give you some more info:

Don't mix thread handles (the thing you store in the pthread_t variable) and what they represent (a thread of execution that runs somewhere). What you were trying to do is to set a property of a thread before it starts, with an API that requires the thread object. As it happens pthread_create creates the object and starts the execution at the same time, so trying to use `pthread_setaffinity_np` is not the right way to go (this is useful if you want to *change* the affinity of a currently running thread).

But... `pthread_create` has an attribute parameter (you're passing NULL to it). This is storing the information of how you want the thread to be created.

Affinity is one of the attributes you can set through that parameter. See the man-page documentation for [`pthread_attr_init`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_init.3.html) and [`pthread_attr_setaffinity_np`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setaffinity_np.3.html) for how exactly

Comment: so I have to pthread_create() them first? But that already runs the function specified... I'm not too sure I understand this whole concept. So I should put the setaffinity function in my pthread_Message() function?

Comment: You don't need to run the thread for very *long* i.e. it could be the first thing the newly created thread does. This would mean that it gets rescheduled, if the new cpu mask didn't include its current cpu.

Comment: I still don't understand... I want to set the affinity mask AFTER pthread_create(), DURING the function that pthread_create() calls, or BEFORE pthread_create()?

Comment: @hahuang65: I added some more info, hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what you were looking for. I know it is a late answer, but this might help others.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
    
int getNumberOfCpus( void )
{
    long nprocs       = -1;
    long nprocs_max   = -1;

# ifdef _SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN
    nprocs = sysconf( _SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN );
    if ( nprocs < 1 )
    {
        //printf("Could not determine number of CPUs on line. Error is %s\n", strerror( errno ));
        return 0;
    }

    nprocs_max = sysconf( _SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF );

    if ( nprocs_max < 1 )
    {
        //printf("Could not determine number of CPUs in host. Error is  %s\n", strerror( errno ));
        return 0;
    }

    //printf("%d of %d online\n", nprocs, nprocs_max);
    return nprocs; 
     
#else
    //printf("Could not determine number of CPUs\n");
    return 0;
#endif
}

void *pthread_Message( void *ptr )
{
    sleep(10);
    char *message;
    message = (char *) ptr;
    printf("%s \n", message);
    cpu_set_t      l_cpuSet;
    int            l_maxCpus;
    int            j;
    unsigned long  l_cpuBitMask;

    CPU_ZERO( &l_cpuSet );
    printf("get affinity %d\n",pthread_getaffinity_np(pthread_self()  , sizeof( cpu_set_t ), &l_cpuSet ));
    // printf("cpuset %d\n",l_cpuSet);
    printf (" thread id %u\n", pthread_self());      

    if ( pthread_getaffinity_np(pthread_self()  , sizeof( cpu_set_t ), &l_cpuSet ) == 0 )
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            if (CPU_ISSET(i, &l_cpuSet))
                printf("XXXCPU: CPU %d\n", i);
    for (long i=0; i< 10000000000; ++i);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread1, thread2, thread3, thread4;
    pthread_t threadArray[4];
    cpu_set_t cpu1, cpu2, cpu3, cpu4;
    const char *thread1Msg = "Thread 1";
    const char *thread2Msg = "Thread 2";
    const char *thread3Msg = "Thread 3";
    const char *thread4Msg = "Thread 4";
    int thread1Create, thread2Create, thread3Create, thread4Create, i, temp;

    thread1Create = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &pthread_Message, (void*)thread1Msg);
    sleep(1);
    thread2Create = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, &pthread_Message, (void*)thread2Msg);
    sleep(1);
    thread3Create = pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, &pthread_Message, (void*)thread3Msg);
    sleep(1);
    thread4Create = pthread_create(&thread4, NULL, &pthread_Message, (void*)thread4Msg);


    CPU_ZERO(&cpu1);
    CPU_SET(0, &cpu1);
    temp = pthread_setaffinity_np(thread1, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpu1);
    printf("setaffinity=%d\n", temp);
    printf("Set returned by pthread_getaffinity_np() contained:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < CPU_SETSIZE; i++)
        if (CPU_ISSET(i, &cpu1))
            printf("CPU1: CPU %d\n", i);

    CPU_ZERO(&cpu2);
    CPU_SET(1, &cpu2);
    temp = pthread_setaffinity_np(thread2, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpu2);
    for (i = 0; i < CPU_SETSIZE; i++)
        if (CPU_ISSET(i, &cpu2))
            printf("CPU2: CPU %d\n", i);

    CPU_ZERO(&cpu3);
    CPU_SET(2, &cpu3);
    temp = pthread_setaffinity_np(thread3, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpu3);
    for (i = 0; i < CPU_SETSIZE; i++)
        if (CPU_ISSET(i, &cpu3))
            printf("CPU3: CPU %d\n", i);

    CPU_ZERO(&cpu4);
    CPU_SET(3, &cpu4);
    temp = pthread_setaffinity_np(thread4, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpu4);
    for (i = 0; i < CPU_SETSIZE; i++)
        if (CPU_ISSET(i, &cpu4))
            printf("CPU4: CPU %d\n", i);

    // pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_self(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpu1);

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread3, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread4, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest would be to give the CPU mask as a parameter to each thread and have the thread request given affinity itself, as in example here: [`pthread_setaffinity_np(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html).

Comment: How do I know which thread (in my case, thread1, thread2, thread3, or thread4) is calling pthread_self()?

Comment: I think Bahbar already answered this - use the thread function parameter, which could really point to anything, say a struct that contains the affinity mask the thread would request for itself. Be careful though not to share the same struct instance between worker threads.