# is pthread_setaffinity_np required to use multiple cores?

Tags: android, linux, multithreading, c++11, pthreads

I'm running a multi-threaded C++ application (freesoft.org's tablebase generator 'hoffman') on a dual core ARM7 running Android 4.1.2 with a Linux 3.0.8 kernel.  Compilation was with gcc 4.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 using linuxonandroid.

I've been experimenting with using pthread_setaffinity_np() to force the different threads onto different cores.  I don't want to do this, but it seems like I must.

Over the course of an hour, playing with different combinations of things, I measured the following run times for a dual threaded benchmark:

with pthread_setaffinity_np(): 10.818, 10.803, 10.814, 11.077, 11.013, 10.952 seconds

without pthread_setaffinity_np(): 20.366, 19.263, 19.539, 16.764, 19.365, 19.661, 19.330 seconds

It seems that the non-standard GNU pthread_setaffinity_np() is absolutely required to get my C++11 program to actually put its threads onto different cores.  'top' confirms that one of my two cores is sitting idle otherwise.

Is this right?  Can anybody offer a better solution?

Comment: maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563442/cpu-affinity-masks-putting-threads-on-different-cpus?rq=1 afaik: all running on 1 core would mean they have a default afinity mask that allows only 1 core which sounds strange.

Comment: Because of NUMA constraints running a common data set over multiple cores can slow down throughput. If the memory data set is largely unique per thread, then pthread_setaffinity_np will work the way you envision. Threads spinkled over several cores all working on pieces of the same physically adjacent memory (like the same page) may not perform  well at all.

Comment: @zapl: I checked the default affinity mask.  it's '3', so both cores are enabled.