# Pinning a thread to a core in a cpuset through C

Tags: c, linux, cpu

I have /cgroup/cpuset/set1. set1 has 2-5,8. I want to bind a process to that cpuset and then pin a thread in that process to, say, core 4. The name of the cpuset and the thread name and the core to which I should bind the thread is in m config file. Are there any C APIs to parse cpuset? What is the correct way to achieve the pinning using C code?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563442/cpu-affinity-masks-putting-threads-on-different-cpus

Comment: There is no language C/C++! These are two different languages.

Comment: @Olaf ok. Corrected to C.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at the `pthread_setaffinity_np` and `pthread_getaffinity_np` functions.

Example:

```
   #define _GNU_SOURCE
   #include <pthread.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <errno.h>

   #define handle_error_en(en, msg) \
           do { errno = en; perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

   int
   main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       int s, j;
       cpu_set_t cpuset;
       pthread_t thread;

       thread = pthread_self();

       /* Set affinity mask to include CPUs 0 to 7 */

       CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
       for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
           CPU_SET(j, &cpuset);

       s = pthread_setaffinity_np(thread, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);
       if (s != 0)
           handle_error_en(s, "pthread_setaffinity_np");

       /* Check the actual affinity mask assigned to the thread */

       s = pthread_getaffinity_np(thread, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);
       if (s != 0)
           handle_error_en(s, "pthread_getaffinity_np");

       printf("Set returned by pthread_getaffinity_np() contained:\n");
       for (j = 0; j < CPU_SETSIZE; j++)
           if (CPU_ISSET(j, &cpuset))
               printf("    CPU %d\n", j);

       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
```

For more details, see the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html).

Comment: Sure, the only reason I found it was your post caused me to stumble across a part of pthreads I'd never seen before, so I went and looked. Thanks.

Comment: How does this work with the original question of cpuset named "set1" ?

Answer (score 4):

Call the following Function and pass whatever core ID you want to pass. Also from wherever you call this function do check its return value to be 1.

```
short CorePin(int coreID)
{
  short status=0;
  int nThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
  //std::cout<<nThreads;
  cpu_set_t set;
  std::cout<<"\nPinning to Core:"<<coreID<<"\n";
  CPU_ZERO(&set);

  if(coreID == -1)
  {
    status=-1;
    std::cout<<"CoreID is -1"<<"\n";
    return status;
  }

  if(coreID > nThreads)
  {
    std::cout<<"Invalid CORE ID"<<"\n";
    return status;
  }

  CPU_SET(coreID,&set);
  if(sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &set) < 0)
  {
    std::cout<<"Unable to Set Affinity"<<"\n";
    return -1;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: It would have been more helpful if it was in C as requested by the original poster.