# Make sure that main thread run on it's own core alone

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a main thread which do some not-so-heavy-heavy work and also I'm creating worker threads which do very-heavy work. All documentation and examples shows how to create a number of hardware threads equal to `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`. But since main thread already existed the number of threads becomes `std::thread::hardware_concurrency() + 1`. For example:

- my machine supports 2 hardware threads.
- in main thread I'm creating this 2 threads and the total number of threads becomes 3.
- a core with the main thread do it's job plus (probably) the worker job.

Of course I don't want this because UI (which is done in main thread) becomes not responsive due to latency. What will happen if I create `std::thread::hardware_concurrency() - 1` thread? Will it guarantee that the main thread and only main thread is running on single core? How can I check it?

P.S.: I'm using some sort of pool - I start threads on the program start and stop on exit. During the execution all worker threads run infinite `while` loop.

Comment: You can't get any guarantee, even if you have fewer threads than the hardware supports. What if other programs are running on the machine? It is up to the OS where it actually runs threads. You may be able to get some improvement with platform specific behaviour. What platform are you targeting?

Comment: What's wrong with letting the OS decide what is best? Why do you think you'll be able to make better decisions than it will?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7/8/10. And I don't think I can do better than OS, I just want my program run smooth.

Comment: @nikitablack just make sure that you are not busy-waiting in your inifinite while-loops. If you're waiting for work, you should use condition-variables.

Comment: Assuming you are not doing bad stuff like waiting/polling in UI event-handlers, just lower the priority of the work threads so that the UI can always get CPU when it becomes ready.  Prabindh has suggested this, a much better and simpler solution than messing around with core affinities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` only gives you a hint about the potential numbers of cores in use for multithreading. You might be interested in [CPU Affinity Masks (Putting Threads on different CPUs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563442/cpu-affinity-masks-putting-threads-on-different-cpus). This works on the pthread level which you can reached via `std::thread::native_handle` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle)

Comment: The asker has pointed out that they are using Windows. Looks like you answered before that comment, but perhaps you could edit your link to some similar functionality for Windows?

Answer (score 3):

As others have written in the comments, you should carefully consider whether you can do a better job than the OS.

That being said, it *is* technically possible:

1. Use the [`native_handle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle) method to get the OS's handle to your thread.
2. Consult your OS's documentation for setting the thread affinity. E.g., using pthreads, you'd want [`pthread_set_affinity`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html).

This gives you full control over where each thread runs. In particular, you can give one of the threads a core of its own.

Note that this isn't part of the standard, as it is a level that is not portable. This might serve as another hint that it's possibly not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your OS, you can get the thread's native handle, and control their priority levels using *pthread_setschedparam()*, for example giving the worker threads a lower priority than the main thread. This can be one solution to the UI problem. In general, number of threads need not match number of available HW cores.

Comment: This is the only answer that seems to be reasonable solution to the OP's actual problem - just lower the priority of the worker threads so that the UI can get CPU quickly when it needs it.   Using core affinity for this requirement is just..  not good.

Answer (score 1):

There are definitely cases where you want to be able to gain full control, and reliably analyze what is going on. You are using Windows, but as an example, it is possible on a multicore machine to exclude e.g. one core from the normal Linux OS scheduler, and use that core for time-critical hard real-time tasks. In essence, you will own that core and handle interrupts for it, thereby enabling something close to hard real-time response times and predictability. Requires careful programming and analysis, and takes a significant effort. But very attractive if done right.

Comment: What does this 'isolated' core do when the ' time-critical hard real-time task' is not ready, and there are other threads that can use CPU?  Just sit there, idle, halted?

Comment: Yes, you dedicate a core and it will not be available for other, best-effort tasks. It will be used exclusively for time-critical tasks that cannot afford to wait for the rest of the OS/user-space processes to do their thing.

Comment: Can't see how it helps much?  When an interrupt occurs to make the critical thread ready, it must obviusly be handled by one of the other cores.  That driver must then interrupt the idle core to make it do stuff again. The only substantial gain I can see is that the L1 cache of the 'critical' core is not polluted by other threads.  The cost is that the rest of the system, including drivers, comms stacks etc. lose the use of one core.  On systems with only a few cores, or with threads that do not use much data compared with L1 size, the gains may not be worth it:(

Comment: @MartinJames: The idea is to split the system into 2 groups, one best-effort handled by 'normal' Linux kernel, and one hard real-time handled separately, and to explicitly bind real-time sensitive interrupts to one the real-time cores. For more details, try to find a copy of 'Enabling Linux for Real-Time on Embedded Multicore Devices' by Patrik Strömblad at ENEA. I got a hardcopy at LinuxCon Europe 2014.